# Firebase cloud messaging multicast error messaging/registration-token-not-registered

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm getting errors with some tokens when using multicast but can't figure out how to know which token the error is related to.

The messages are sent with the firebase admin sdk in nodejs like this, where tokenChunk is an array of FCM tokens:

```
firebaseAdmin.messaging().sendMulticast({
                    notification: {
                        title: title,
                        body: message,
                    },
                    data: data,
                    tokens: tokenChunk,
                })
                .then((success) => {
                    if (success.responses) {
                        success.responses.forEach((response) => {
                            if (response.error) {
                                if (response.error?.errorInfo?.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
                                    // there is no token reference in this entire response to know which one to delete, only the error
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    return success;
                })
```

the error looks something like this:

```
FirebaseMessagingError: Requested entity was not found.
      at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:44:28)
      at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:90:28)
      at new FirebaseMessagingError (/var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:279:16)
      at Function.FirebaseMessagingError.fromServerError (/var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:312:16)
      at Object.createFirebaseError (/var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-errors-internal.js:35:47)
      at FirebaseMessagingRequestHandler.buildSendResponse (/var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request-internal.js:122:56)
      at /var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request-internal.js:97:30
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at /var/task/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request-internal.js:96:30
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5) {
    errorInfo: {
      code: 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered',
      message: 'Requested entity was not found.'
    },
    codePrefix: 'messaging'
  }
```

Should they just match in order of the responses? So if `success.responses[4]` had an error, then the token would be `tokenChunk[4]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started logging the errors & token at the same index in the multicast responses, and after manually checking each token it seems to be no longer registered/erroring with token at the same index.

So to confirm, the response array from sendMulticast is in the **same order** as the tokens that were passed in, allowing you to match up the indexes of any errors.

In this example, token 'def' is the one not registered because the error is on the second response item:

```
tokens: [
  'abc',
  'def',
  'ghi',
]
...
//send multicast
...
success.responses: [
 {
  //success response
 },
 {
   error: {
     errorInfo: {
       code: 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered',
     },
   },
 },
 {
  //success response
 },
```